# Unique Letter from users inputted field c#

Tags: c#

How to output unique letters from user input except case and other symbols without LINQ and using only List?

```
Console.Write("Please enter some text: ");

var text = Console.ReadLine();

var uniqueLetters = new List<string>();

uniqueLetters.Add(text);

var unique = new List<string>();

foreach (var n in uniqueLetters)
{
    if (!unique.Contains(n))
    {
        unique.Add(n);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Output: " + string.Join(",", unique));`
```

Comment: What means "except other symbols"?

Comment: Also, you want unique strings(words) or unique chars? Because your `foreach` just enumerates one string and not the characters of this string.

Comment: @ , $ and etc, unique strings(words)

Comment: @Antonie: What does `@ , $ and etc,` mean? These symbols can be duplicated?

Comment: Why can't you use Linq? Why can't you use Dictionary<T>?

Comment: Can you use `HashSet<char>`? Is this homework?

Comment: Symbols can be duplicated, HashSet yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `HashSet<string>` with `IgnoreCase`-comparer to check if it's a duplicate:

```
var uniqueLettersExceptCaseAndSymbols = new List<char>();
var letterDuplicateChecker = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

foreach (char c in text)
{
    if(!char.IsLetter(c) || letterDuplicateChecker.Add(c.ToString()))
        uniqueLettersExceptCaseAndSymbols.Add(c);
}

string result = String.Join(",", uniqueLettersExceptCaseAndSymbols);
```

Comment: Is it possible to output unique letters without String.Join?
 **Aplplewlrekjntkjg dsg6565** > **Aplewrkjntg ds6565**

Comment: @Antonio99: sure, you can use `String.Concat(uniqueLettersExceptCaseAndSymbols)`

Comment: Thanks for help!!